# plsql block not executing

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

I am unable to execute this block. it just compiles. what statement I have togive to see output. where I am doing error ? I clicked on output button also

[image: picture click here]

[image]

Comment: oracle express 11g and sql developer 4.1.3 latest one. When I execute it says compiled but no output.  ? new to plsql

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'SMA' reference is out of scope
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: It's best to edit your original question (use the "edit" link) and post the full error message there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats is not what you should execute. `sma` is the procedure, `c4` is simply a cursor in it. You do not execute the cursor local to a procedure, you can not even access it. Execute the below:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  sma;
end;
/
```